# Using XPath in java with if statements?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Im trying to merge & evaluate xml using xpath in Java.
I know its xpath 1.0, and 2.0 added if statements.
Im still trying to resolve the issue, hopefuly with your help.
so, 2 files:
1. data.xml
2. view.xml
view.xml contains attributes with xpath expressions, for example:

```
<item name="/names/name" .... />
```

I wish to read the entire view.xml as dom-tree, then select all the attributes with xpath expressions and evaluate them.
in this case, with a data.xml such as:

```
<names>
<name>Bon</name>
</names>
```

I expect my resulting dom-tree to be:

```
<item name="Bon" .... />
```

so far, that isnt too problematic.
The issue comes where I want to be more demanding, such as "if /names/name="Bon" return "name exists"
so that the result would be

```
<item name="name exists" .... />
```

What possible ways I have to do such a thing with Java xpath engine (or maybe something else?)

Comment: The built-in XPath engine that comes with the JDK is XPath 1.0, but XPath 2.0 is available for Java if you need it, for example using Saxon or PsychoPath.

Comment: Its really unclear, both Saxon or XPath. Where can I find good references to study it / examples to see?

Comment: For Saxon, see the documentation on the www.saxonica.com site